# Find the kernel of this linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Below is a problem from an online class that I am taking (not for credit or anything so I'm not just asking someone to do my homework; it is just bugging me that I cannot figure it out). I am not sure if there is some kind of gap in my knowledge, but I do not know how I would approach a mapping defined by a matrix whose entries are Laurent polynomials. I feel like I might just be able to solve it as a system but I'm not really sure how proceed.

Find the kernel of the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{C}^3(t)\to \mathbb{C}^3(t)$ defined by the matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & t^{-1}\\
0 & t & 0\\
0 & 1 & t^{-1}+t
\end{pmatrix}$

EDIT (My seemingly incorrect attempt):

- I am a little confused because the problem said that the mapping acts on the right—doesn't that not work with matrix multiplication? Or am I mixing up the definition of acting on the right? In any case, I did it below with what seems to be the the mapping acting. on the left (?)

Find $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$ such that

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & t^{-1}\\
0 & t & 0\\
0 & 1 & t^{-1}+t
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
So
$$\left(\begin{array}{c} b+\frac{c}{t}\\ b\,t\\ b+c\,\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right) \end{array}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
This is impossible, so the kernel is empty?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! What have you tried so far? Where exactly did you get stuck? A good starting point would be to apply the definition of the kernel.

Comment: What is the vector space?

Comment: @Bernard the vector space is $\mathbb{C}^3(t)$.

Comment: On which base field? $\mathbf C$? $\mathbf C(t)$?

Comment: @Bernard (I think) $\mathbb{C}(t)$

Comment: If the mapping acts on the right, then you are asking to find the set of $(a,b,c)$ which satisfies  $$(a,b,c)\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & t^{-1}\\
0 & t & 0\\
0 & 1 & t^{-1}+t
\end{pmatrix} = (0,0,0)$$

Comment: Where did your vector $\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}$ come from? It should be the zero vector.

Comment: @Berci would it be correct if I instead used the zero vector? And so the answer is that $b=c=0$ and $a$ is anything?

Comment: Well, if it indeed acts on the right, then you have to consider a *row vector* instead of a column vector, thus it will lead to different solution. Alternatively, you're about to find the kernel of the *transpose matrix*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that $\ \mathbb{C}^3(t)\ $ is the vector space of ordered triples over the field of complex rational functions of the indeterminate $\ t\ $.  Then $\ (a(t),b(t),c(t))\ $ is in the kernel of $\ T\ $ if and only if
$$
\pmatrix{a(t),b(t),c(t)}\pmatrix{0&1&t^{-1}\\
0&t&0\\
0&1&t^{-1}+t}=(0,0,0)\\
\Leftrightarrow\left\{ \begin{matrix}a(t)+tb(t)+c(t)=0\\
\frac{a(t)}{t}+\frac{\left(1+t^2\right)c(t)}{t}=0\end{matrix}\right.\\
\Leftrightarrow\left\{ \begin{matrix}a(t)=-\left(1+t^2\right)c(t)\\
b(t)=tc(t)\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Thus, the kernel of the transformation is
$$
\left\{\left.f(t)\left(1+t^2,-t,-1\right)\,\right|f(t)\in\mathbb{C}^3(t)\right\}\ .
$$